# Add id_token as claim AspNetCore OpenIdConnect middleware

Tags: claims-based-identity, openid-connect, identityserver3, .net-core-rc2

I am trying to set `IdTokenHint` when sending the sign out request. In the previous `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` middleware I would be able to set the `id_token` as a claim in the `SecurityTokenValidated` method using the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification by doing something like this:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ...
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        //Perform claims transformation
        SecurityTokenValidated = async notification =>
        {
            ...
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", notification.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
        },
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
        {
            if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
            {
                var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

With the new middleware `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` (in ASP.NET Core RC2) I am having trouble trying to accomplish the same thing. I am assuming I should tap into the `Events` like so.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ...
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
         OnTokenValidated = context =>
         {
             ...
             context.SecurityToken.Payload.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
          },
          OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
          {
                var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
        }
     }
 }
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the claims do not remain on the `SecurityToken` and don't get set on the `HttpContext.User`. What am I missing?

Comment: IIRC the OIDC middleware sends it automatically.

Comment: You are correct, it looks like it is including the `idTokenHint` on the logout request automatically. I'm not sure how I missed it the first time around!

I am curious how claims transformation works in the new OIDC middleware though.

Comment: Claims transformation is also built-in as a middleware. It's quite easy.

Comment: @BrockAllen  Hi! I am facing the same issue with .Net Core. Although I am using _OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut_ event, _n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType_ remains _Authentication_ and I can't find _"id_token"_ claim. Could you please let me know what could be wrong here?

Comment: I've got the same problem/question as @AparnaGadgil

Comment: It wont be a claim if i remember properly. Try `context.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token")`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your code above, at least in version 2.1 of ASP.NET Core, the ID token can be accessed via `context.Properties.GetTokenValue(...)` (rather than as a user claim).

And, as Brock Allen said in a [comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576666/add-id-token-as-claim-aspnetcore-openidconnect-middleware#comment62642904_37576666), the `OpenIdConnectHandler` will automatically include the `idTokenHint` on sign out. However, and this bit me for a few hours today, when the handler processes the sign-in callback, it will only save the tokens for later if `OpenIdConnectOptions.SaveTokens` is set to `true`. The default is `false`, i.e., the tokens are no longer available when you do the sign-out.

So, if `SaveTokens` is `true`, the handler will automatically include the `idTokenHint` on logout, and you can also manually access the `id token` via `context.Properties.GetTokenValue(...)`.